# Unexplainable Null Reference Exception in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-io, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

I have an application for working with files. It needs to work with the files one character at a time. I am using an `ArrayList` to store the data. Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
Dim fileData As ArrayList = Nothing  
Dim temp As Char = Nothing  
While Not EOF(open_file_number)  
    Input(open_file_number, temp)  
    fileData.Add(temp)  
End While
```

The line of code that is throwing the Null Reference Exception is where I (attempt to) assign the value of `temp` to a new element in the `fileData ArrayList`. Anybody have an idea of what's going on here? Thanks

Comment: *Everything* is explainable. ;)

Comment: I don't think `Dim fileData as New ArrayList = Nothing` is valid... are you declaring it `New` or setting it to `Nothing`? That will make a difference

Comment: @Mehrdad Well, does anyone have an explanation for this? cause I sure don't.

Comment: oops I didn't mean to put the New in... force of habit I guess. That's not the way it is in the code. I'll change it. Thanks for catching that, @mellamokb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `fileData` is set to `Nothing`, so of course it will fire a `NullReferenceException` when you call `.Add` on it.  Try setting it to a new instance:

```
Dim fileData As New ArrayList
```

Comment: OK I see it now `*smacks hand into forehead*` I thought the null reference was on temp

Comment: @Nate: null references don't happen when passing arguments.  It's perfectly valid to pass a `Nothing` for a parameter.  null reference exception will only happen when attempting to access a property or call a method on a null object.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is change the following line:

```
Dim temp As Char = Nothing
```

To:

```
Dim temp as Char = ''
```

There **is** a difference.  I have experienced the same thing with String variables and have gotten the same issue.

```
Dim s as String = nothing
```

results in a NULL pointer when attempting to assign a value to 's'.

```
Dim s as string = String.empty
```

Does not.